# "I'm not being confusing?" -> why Being?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

> A: A wild dog?
>
> B: I'm not **being confusing** on purpose. Their bites are nasty.

Why did B use 'being confusing'? What if B said like...

"I'm not confusing"

"I don't confuse"

then how would it be changed in mood or grammar?

Comment: Hmm. I agree it's confusing. I can't really explain why we'd almost never use intransitive ***It confuses**.* But it's worth noting that we're quite happy to use transitive ***It confuses many people*** as an alternative to ***It is confusing to/for many people***.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you say that someone **is confusing**, then you are saying that is something about them - that they are always confusing, or tend to be confusing. If someone **is being confusing**, then it is only what they are doing at that point that is confusing.